# Callback for task, why does the UI thread block

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

I have the following piece of code:

```
public static async Task<SqlConnection> OpenSqlConnectionAsync()
{
    if (_SqlConnection == default(SqlConnection))
    {
        _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    }
    if (_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || _SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
    {
        _SqlConnection.ConnectionString = SqlConnectionStuff.GetConnectionString;
        Task ConnectionTask = _SqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        await ConnectionTask.ContinueWith((PreviousTask) =>
       {

       }
        );
        if (_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Text = "Connection opened!"; });
        }
        else
        {
            MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Text = "Connection not opened!"; });
        }
    }
    return GetSqlConnection;
}
```

In a separate class with the hopefully describing name SqlConnectionStuff... (no worries it will get changed soon ;P)

And down in my Window code there's is written the following:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnectionStuff.OpenSqlConnectionAsync().Wait();
}
```

So when Invoking this using the Wait method behind the Task, stops the execution at the **ContinueWith** callback @ the **OpenSqlConnectionAsync** method.
The window freezes. It doesn't seem to finish and it looks like the UI thread is getting blocked, which makes sense from my rudimentary insights into the behaviour of the threads. It is not necessary for it to block at all but this method has to be executed before anything else will work so it won't matter at all if the user input is locked as long as the connection is established.

My interest now would be, why if I remove the Wait() instruction, the **await** on the callback seems to be executed flawlessly without getting stuck (as it is an empty instruction which can't fail obv.), and afterwards the information for the user is displayed in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnectionStuff.OpenSqlConnectionAsync().Wait();
}
```

...specifically the `Wait()` blocks the UI thread from executing.  By the way, calling an `async` method then explicitly blocking on it by calling `Wait` defeats the purpose of `async/await` by the way.  It's like spinning up a thread only to `Join` on it.  There are times when its ok to do so like when the signature of the method can't be changed to `async` (as in console apps `Main` methods prior to C# 7)

Meanwhile the following code attempts to synchonously thread marshal from whatever is the current thread to the UI thread in order to have the UI thread update the `lblCursorPosition.Text` property.

```
MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
       { MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Text = "Connection opened!"; });
```

Unforunately as we already mentioned, the UI thread is **already busy** waiting for `OpenSqlConnectionAsync` to complete.  So now you have a case of both ends waiting on the other.  You have a **deadlock**.

A fix would be to change the method signature like so and call `await`:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // <-- note async
{
    // await synchronously
    await SqlConnectionStuff.OpenSqlConnectionAsync(); // await here. No Wait()
}
```

You could fix it another way by changing `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`.  The latter *posts* the action *asynchronously* to the UI thread.  The net effect would be `OpenSqlConnectionAsync` would return the `GetSqlConnection`; the UI thread would resume following the `Wait()`; and later process the updating of the `Label`.

```
MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
      { MainWindow.Instance.lblCursorPosition.Text = "Connection opened!"; });
```

Comment: So at any place possible just try to use fire and forget? :P But it makes sense at all... If I wouldn't marshal to the UI thread it would not occur right? So is some kind of queue for operations on the UI thread a proper way to tackle this? Thanks for the explanation btw. I got it!

Comment: @mayen 1) A best practice is to use `BeginInvoke` always so you don't shoot yourself in the foot accidentally.  Plus you want to avoid calling `Wait()` when calling an `async` method from a method that is `async` aware.  `Wait()` defeats the purpose of concurrency. 2) Thread marshalling is going to occur with both `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`.  The former sort of attempts to bypass the queue and act on it immediately whilst the latter does not.  Yes queue is best.  Under the hood, mouse move; clicks; keyboard; window sizing; paint etc all happens with the Windows Message pump (queue).

Comment: Alright thanks for making me a bit more knowledgeable again! I will accept your answer =) If new questions come up I will pose then in a new topic.

Comment: @mayen: Don't use fire and forget. The key is to use `await` instead of `Wait`.

Comment: Neither `Invoke` nor `BeginInvoke` should really ever be used. `IProgress<T>` is far superior.

Comment: I think I need to look into Concurrency best practices more then I did before. Thanks for mentioning your perspective. Your book seems to be a good starting point also, it will become an item on my to read list. I found a solution for this problem though but I'm not sure if this is a remotely practiced way or internally the threads are now handled as I wished them to. Guess that will become clearer after the first tests :D

Comment: With await it is fine btw. First time with real concurrency as a goal. It is somewhat mysterious to rookies like me. Also that you can send even event methods as async was new to me actually. So theres many questions left unanswered which would require testing more ... or reading more... are the methods executed completely before the thread continues or is it async as the rest would be? If an event handler method is marked async?